# Train Loss and validation loss GradientBoostingClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am learning to do classification for Cover Type data for 7 classes. I train my model with GradientBoostingClassifier from scikit-learn. When I try to plot my loss function this goes like this:

[image]

Is this kind of plot shows me that my model suffers from high variance? If yes, what should I do? And I don't know why in the middle of iterations 200 until 500, the plot is shaped like a rectangle.

**(EDIT)**
To edit this post, I'm not sure what's wrong with my code becaue I just used the regular code to fit the training data. I'm using jupyter notebook. So I'm just going to provide the code

```
Y = train["Cover_Type"]
X = train.drop({"Cover_Type"}, axis=1) 

#split training data dan cross validation
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_val, Y_train, Y_val = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.3,random_state=42)

from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.datasets import make_friedman1
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier

params = {'n_estimators': 1000,'learning_rate': 0.3, 'max_features' : 'sqrt'}

dtree=GradientBoostingClassifier(**params)
dtree.fit(X_train,Y_train)

#mau lihat F1-Score
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

Y_pred = dtree.predict(X_val) #prediksi data cross validation menggunakan model tadi
print Y_pred
score = f1_score(Y_val, Y_pred, average="micro") 

print("Gradient Boosting Tree F1-score: "+str(score)) # I got 0.86 F1-Score

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Plot training deviance

# compute test set deviance
val_score = np.zeros((params['n_estimators'],), dtype=np.float64)

for i, Y_pred in enumerate(dtree.staged_predict(X_val)):
    val_score[i] = dtree.loss_(Y_val, Y_pred.reshape(-1, 1))

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.title('Deviance')
plt.plot(np.arange(params['n_estimators']) + 1, dtree.train_score_, 'b-',
             label='Training Set Deviance')
plt.plot(np.arange(params['n_estimators']) + 1, val_score, 'r-',
             label='Validation Set Deviance')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.xlabel('Boosting Iterations')
plt.ylabel('Deviance')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues that I will explain them one by one, also I have added the correct code for your example.

1. **`staged_predict(X)` method shall NOT be used**

   - As `staged_predict(X)` outputs the predicted class instead of predicted probabilities, it is not correct to use that.
   - One can (where the context accept) use `staged_decision_function(X)` method and pass the computed decisions at each stage to the `model.loss_` attribute. But in [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.fetch_covtype.html) example, it does not work (the loss based on staged decision increases while the loss decreases).
2. **You should use `staged_predict_proba(X)` with cross entropy loss**

   - you should use `staged_predict_proba(X)`
   - you also need to define a function that calculate the cross entropy loss at each stage.
   - I have provided the code below. Note that I set the verbosity to 2, and then you can see that the sklearn training loss at each stage is the same as our loss (as a sanity check that our approach works correctly).
3. **Why you have big jumps**

   - I think the reason is that GBC becomes very confident and then predict a label is 1 (as an example) with probability **one**, while it is not correct (for example the label is 2). This creates big jumps (as cross entropy goes to infinity). In such a scenario you should change your GBC parameters.
4. **The code and the Plot are given below**

   - The code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_covtype
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier


def _cross_entropy_like_loss(model, input_data, targets, num_estimators):
    loss = np.zeros((num_estimators, 1))
    for index, predict in enumerate(model.staged_predict_proba(input_data)):
        loss[index, :] = -np.sum(np.log([predict[sample_num, class_num-1]
                                         for sample_num, class_num in enumerate(targets)])) 
        print(f'ce loss {index}:{loss[index, :]}')
    return loss


covtype = fetch_covtype()
X = covtype.data
Y = covtype.target
n_estimators = 10
X_train, X_val, Y_train, Y_val = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
clf = GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=n_estimators, learning_rate=0.3, verbose=2 )
clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)


tr_loss_ce = _cross_entropy_like_loss(clf, X_train, Y_train, n_estimators)
test_loss_ce = _cross_entropy_like_loss(clf, X_val, Y_val, n_estimators)


plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.arange(n_estimators) + 1, tr_loss_ce, '-r', label='training_loss_ce')
plt.plot(np.arange(n_estimators) + 1, test_loss_ce, '-b', label='val_loss_ce')
plt.ylabel('Error')
plt.xlabel('num_components')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
```

- The output of console is like below, from which you can easily verify the approach is correct.

```
     Iter       Train Loss   Remaining Time 
         1      482434.6631            1.04m
         2      398501.7223           55.56s
         3      351391.6893           48.51s
         4      322290.3230           41.60s
         5      301887.1735           34.65s
         6      287438.7801           27.72s
         7      276109.2008           20.82s
         8      268089.2418           13.84s
         9      261372.6689            6.93s
        10      256096.1205            0.00s
ce loss 0:[ 482434.6630936]
ce loss 1:[ 398501.72228276]
ce loss 2:[ 351391.68933547]
ce loss 3:[ 322290.32300604]
ce loss 4:[ 301887.17346783]
ce loss 5:[ 287438.7801033]
ce loss 6:[ 276109.20077844]
ce loss 7:[ 268089.2418214]
ce loss 8:[ 261372.66892149]
ce loss 9:[ 256096.1205235]
```

- [The plot is here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XA7ek.png)

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you have several issues. It's hard to say for sure, because you don't provide any code.

## Does my model suffer from high variance?

First, *your model is overfitting from the start*. You can tell that this is the case since your validation loss is increasing although your training is decreasing. What's interesting is that your validation loss is increasing from the very start, which suggests that your model is not working. So to answer your question, yes, it suffers from high variance.

## What should I do?

Are you sure there is a trend in your data? The fact that the validation increases *from the very start* hints that either this model does not apply to your data at all, that your data does not have a trend, or that you have issues with your code. Perhaps try other models, and make sure your code is correct. Again, it's hard to say without a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

## The strange rectangle

This looks strange. Either there is an issue with your data in the validation set (because this impact does not occur on the validation set) or you just have an issue with your code. If you provide a sample, we could probably help you more.

Comment: I'm sorry what is a " trend " in data ? I don't know what it is